# How does gnome shell know which config file to use from /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/?

Tags: gnome-shell

The directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/` contains the following configuration files that specify which style sheet to use, from the specified gresource, for the Gnome Shell Top Bar, Dash, and Lock Screen.

```
initial-setup.json
ubuntu.json
yaru.json
```

How does gnome shell know which of these config files to use/load?

There must be a place where the names `initial-setup`, `ubuntu`, or `yaru` are configured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is from the `Ubuntu` session which is the default at login screen.

[image]

session Name Ubuntu -> is the one `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop`

and its contents are

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu
TryExec=/usr/bin/gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-GDM-SessionRegisters=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

Observe the line `Exec=` in which it is setting the environment variable

```
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this file controls X-Org sessions, while `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/ubuntu-wayland.desktop` does the same for Wayland sessions?

Comment: This works really well. I was able to add a "Ubuntu Custom" option on the login screen by creating  `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-custom.desktop` file.This file points to a customized `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` (through `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/`), so I do not need to replace the original `.gresource` file and worry about system updates reverting it. I also tested creating an option for Wayland by creating a `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/ubuntu-custom-wayland.desktop` file and it works as well.